# Reset the data after unchecking the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have some results in div's ,each result has one `checkbox` associated with it, when a user click on single checkbox user, Current checked box's value is passed to another page using an ajax call and data is fetched and displayed in a hidden div box.

Now problem is, when user `uncheck` the `checkbox` it should remove the data associated with the checkbox.

My code is :

```
<div id='compare_box'>                  
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 photo-grid " style="float:left">              
  <div class="well well-sm">             
    <a href="final.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&name=<?php echo $title;?>" target="_blank">
      <h4><small><?php echo $title; ?></small></h4>
    </a>
    <br>
    <input type ='checkbox' name="compare" class="compare" value="<?php echo $id;?>">add to compare
  </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax call**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{


    $(".compare").change(function() {
      if(this.checked) {  
      var check = $(this).val();      
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'compare.php',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        data:{value : check},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            $('#compare_box').append(data);

        }
    });
}

 });
});
```

[image: result][image: main problem]

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this to empty the contents of the DIV

```
     $('#compare_box').empty()
```

Comment: don't you think it will empty the whole div if i uncheck the checkbox,i need to remove only current selected result if i uncheck,i need something like toggle() function,but don't know where exactly i should use it

Answer (score 0):

better way is to keep the reference map, something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var boxes = {};
  $(".compare").change(function() {
    var check = $(this).val();
    var data = $(this).closest('.box').clone();

    if (this.checked) {
      boxes[check] = data;
      $('#comparebox').append(boxes[check]);
    } else if (!this.checked && boxes[check]) {
      boxes[check].remove();
      delete boxes[check];
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT - should be working (*not tested*)

```
var check = $(this).val();
if (this.checked) {      
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'compare.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
      value: check
    },
    success: function(data) {
      boxes[check] = $(data);
      $('#compare_box').append(boxes[check]);
    }
  });
} else if(!this.checked && boxes[check]) {
    boxes[check].remove();
    delete boxes[check];
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltcg16c8/)

Comment: how to integrate this with ajax call result's data

Comment: i think we should declare boxes[check] array before assigning json data to it